# jQuery Autocomplete - prevent call on specific keypress (left & right arrow)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Given a simple autocomplete as per code below, how can I avoid a call to autocomplete only when pressing specific keys (in this case, the left and right arrows)

Just to be clear, the call I want to avoid is the `autocomplete` one (which returns the list of autocomplete suggestions), as opposed to the `select` one

I presume I need to `event.stopPropagation` (as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116017/jqueryui-autocomplete-prevent-call-on-every-keypress)), however it is unclear to me how to limit this to specific keys

```
    $("#myAutoComplete").autocomplete({   
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: some_json_package,
                success: response,
                dataType: 'json'
            });
        },        
        minLength: 2,
        select: autocompleteSelectFunction,
    });
```

*Edit: for further clarification of this use case, the problem is that when the user navigates with right and left arrows to edit the autocomplete, the component believes an edit has been made and calls autocomplete, thus generating a new list of suggestions (identical to the previous, since the user has inputed no new data, just moved the arrows left or right)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit dirty, but here's a working solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/9sz4pjqc/

It will only call the source if the last key pressed is NOT the left or right arrow. I used the default jQuery UI Autocomplete example because JSON of course didn't work in JSfiddle, but I'm sure you can refine this example to your own situation ;-)

This little script will save the last key pressed in a variable:

```
$('#myAutoComplete').on("keyup", function(e) {
  var code = (e.keyCode || e.which);
  if (code == 37 || code == 39) {
    arrowKeyPressed = 1;
    console.log('Left/Right');
  } else {
    arrowKeyPressed = 0;
    console.log('Not Left/Right');
  }
});
```

And this modification of the `source` will make it so that a source is only provided to the autocomplete if the last key pressed is NOT the left or right arrow:

```
source: function(request, response) {
    if (arrowKeyPressed == 0) {
      response( *** YOUR ORIGINAL AJAX/JSON SOURCE HERE *** );
    }
  }
```

To give a bit credit where credit is due, my solution is based upon work of these geniouses: [Show Jquery UI Autocomplete only when a special key is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16531903/show-jquery-ui-autocomplete-only-when-a-special-key-is-pressed)

Comment: So you're using a global variable to keep track and then check it in source. Good thanks, also for the link